Using JSON schema from external source in swagger in NET8 web API project
NET8 Web API project.
My controller actions don't have a typed input parameter. The incoming JSON is readed from request body stream and validated against the schema using NJsonSchema and sent either to another service or saved to the database. No manipulations are performed on it.
The project has a swagger enabled and in this situation it does not show the scheme for the input parameter in swagger-ui. But I need the input parameter scheme (by which this is validated) to be visible in UI as well as in the final OpenAPI specification (swagger.json) file.  Are there any ready-made solutions or nugget packages for this situation?
I look towards the package Microsoft.OpenApi.Readers, but things a little bit complicated there.
Simplified code example:
[HttpPost("upload")]
[ProducesResponseType<SimpleModel>(200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    using var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    var requestBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

    // Used for checking is JSON valid
    var model = JObject.Parse(requestBody);

    var validationErrors = _jsonSchema.Validate(model);

    if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
        return BadRequest(validationErrors);

    /*
     * do some useful non typed stuff with input model  
    */

    return Ok();
}



You could Swagger Operation Filter to add the schema, below is the sample code:
MainController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NJsonSchema;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JsonSchemaValidationApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly JsonSchema _jsonSchema;

        public MainController()
        {
            // Load JSON schema from file
            _jsonSchema = JsonSchema.FromFileAsync("SimpleModelSchema.json").Result;
        }

        [HttpPost("upload")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SimpleModel), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
        {
            using var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
            var requestBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            // Parse the JSON and validate it against the schema
            var model = JObject.Parse(requestBody);
            var validationErrors = _jsonSchema.Validate(model);

            if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
                return BadRequest(validationErrors);

            return Ok(new { Message = "JSON is valid", Data = model });
        }
    }
}

AddJsonSchemaOperationFilter.cs:
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using NJsonSchema;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace JsonSchemaValidationApi
{
    public class AddJsonSchemaOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Load the JSON schema file and convert it to OpenApiSchema
                var jsonSchema = LoadJsonSchema("SimpleModelSchema.json");

                operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody
                {
                    Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
                    {
                        ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                        {
                            Schema = jsonSchema
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        private OpenApiSchema LoadJsonSchema(string filePath)
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            var schema = JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(json).Result;

            var openApiSchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = ConvertJsonObjectTypeToOpenApiType(schema.Type),
                Properties = schema.Properties.ToDictionary(
                    prop => prop.Key,
                    prop => new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = ConvertJsonObjectTypeToOpenApiType(prop.Value.Type),
                        Format = prop.Value.Format
                    })
            };

            return openApiSchema;
        }

        private string ConvertJsonObjectTypeToOpenApiType(JsonObjectType jsonObjectType)
        {
            return jsonObjectType switch
            {
                JsonObjectType.String => "string",
                JsonObjectType.Number => "number",
                JsonObjectType.Integer => "integer",
                JsonObjectType.Boolean => "boolean",
                JsonObjectType.Array => "array",
                JsonObjectType.Object => "object",
                _ => "string"
            };
        }

    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<AddJsonSchemaOperationFilter>();
});


